# Git Submodule git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey) error

Tags: git, github, ssh

When I run
`git submodule add -f git@github.com:VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git .vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`
this happens

```
Cloning into '/home/ridhwaans/dotfiles/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim'... 
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights 
and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@github.com:VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git' into submodule path '/home/ridhwaans/dotfiles/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

Im in the base directory of the .git project, ssh key is active,`ssh -T git@github.com` returns valid, I rather not use the https url.
why does this occur and how do you fix it

Answer (score 0):

[`VundleVim/Vundle.vim`](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) is a public repository on GitHub.

So for a submodule, you don't need to use the SSH URL:

```
git submodule add -f https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git .vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

But if you don't want to use HTTPS, you can try and see what is blocking with (assuming Linux):

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"
git ls-remote git@github.com:VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git
git submodule add -f git@github.com:VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git .vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```